# Get USB address

Tags: usb, python, linux, raspbian-wheezy

I have a FTDI USB-Serial (UART) IC connected to my Raspberry Pi. When I type `lsusb` I can see all my USB buses:

```
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 0424:9512 Standard Microsystems Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0424:ec00 Standard Microsystems Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 050d:705c Belkin Components F5D7050 Wireless G Adapter v4000 [Zydas ZD1211B]
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 0403:6001 Future Technology Devices International, Ltd FT232 USB-Serial (UART) IC
```

I am using `python-serial` to communicate with the USB via Serial. For this I need the address:

```
ser = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyUSB0',  9600, timeout = 0.1)
```

By trial and error I determined the address is `/dev/ttyUSB0`. I went to directory `/dev/` and took a guess. Where can I find a mapping of (in this case) Device 0005 to the actual address?

Getting the USB tree `lusub -t` yields:

```
lsusb -t
/:  Bus 01.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=dwc_otg/1p, 480M
    |__ Port 1: Dev 2, If 0, Class=hub, Driver=hub/3p, 480M
        |__ Port 1: Dev 3, If 0, Class=vend., Driver=smsc95xx, 480M
        |__ Port 2: Dev 5, If 0, Class=vend., Driver=ftdi_sio, 12M
        |__ Port 3: Dev 4, If 0, Class=vend., Driver=zd1211rw, 480M
```

but does not tell me the address.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will find it using `lshw` command:

```
lshw -businfo -numeric -class usb
```

Will print everything you need. Non-standard Debian but useful, you may want the `hwinfo` command which produce detailed informations.

Comment: Thanks but I am using the wheezy distro and neither `hwinfo` or `lshw` are valid. I get `-bash: lshw: command not found`

Comment: So am I. You can install it from the Raspian distro, just issue `sudo apt-get install hwinfo`.

Answer (score 5):

After plugging in the device, (or after boot if it's already plugged in), you should see in dmesg what the device has been registered as in /dev. The device registration will also trigger a udev call. You can create a custom rule to always assign it to a specific device.

For example, creating a  /udev/rules.d/90serial file with this should work, and create /dev/myUSBserial:

```
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTR{idVendor}=="0403", MODE:="666", SYMLINK+="myUSBserial"
```

[More info](http://hintshop.ludvig.co.nz/show/persistent-names-usb-serial-devices/).