# RS-485 and Raspberry Pi

Tags: raspbian, modbus

How does [RS-485](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RS-485) communication between Raspberry Pi and various sensors work?

**Note**: I would like to use it with Pyhton 2.7.

Can I connect [ADM485](http://www.analog.com/static/imported-files/data_sheets/ADM485.pdf) to the [UART](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_asynchronous_receiver/transmitter) (Tx, Rx) of Raspberry Pi? I want to use [minimalmodbus](http://minimalmodbus.sourceforge.net/) to communicate with Arduinos receiving information from multiple temperature sensors.

Any there any references to this? I read the documentation of [minimalmodbus](http://minimalmodbus.sourceforge.net/) and it sounds great. Can I go forward or is there any other better Python mdoules for a beginner like me?

Answer (score 9):

**1- Managing the send / recieve modes by soft will most likely result in failure for the communication**

[Ref.Link to be inserted here]

I am trying to hook up a Tristar TS-MPPT-60 to a Raspberry Pi using an RS-485 chip connected to the Raspberry Pi UART, and eventually add my Arduinos to the network.
I have some [MAX485](http://datasheets.maximintegrated.com/en/ds/MAX1487-MAX491.pdf) chips and a [SparkFun](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SparkFun_Electronics) RS-485 BOB to do my tests.

References:

- [TS-MPPT-60 Manual](http://africanenergy.com/new/wp-content/uploads/2012/08/tsmppt_english-manual.pdf)
- [TS-MPPT-60 MODBUS](http://www.soligent.net/uploads/products/24886_7.pdf)
- [RS-485 BOB](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/10124)

**2- To let the Raspberry Pi control the RTS / CTS you need access to pins 30 and 31**

- *[P5 header](http://elinux.org/RPi_Low-level_peripherals#P5_header)*
- *[Raspberry Pi P5 Header](http://www.raspberrypi-spy.co.uk/2012/09/raspberry-pi-p5-header/#prettyPhoto)*
- *[The leaning header of Pi5a. How best to solder a header on P5?](http://raspi.tv/2013/the-leaning-header-of-pi5a-how-best-to-solder-a-header-on-p5)*

Here is what I got hooked up, but not tested yet:
Original image: http://www.homegenie.it/forum/index.php?topic=208.0

[image]

3- **To use the UART you need to have it released by the Raspberry Pi internal use (undesired traffic)**:

- [Are you lucky? No USB to serial converter needed!](https://dl8scu.wordpress.com/2013/02/10/are-you-lucky-no-usb-to-serial-converter-needed/)
- [bw_rpi_tools](https://github.com/rewolff/bw_rpi_tools)

The MakeFile is broken. Do not forget to fix this code for the gpio_setfunc function to compile:

```
In the Makefile change the line:

cp $(BINARIES) $(SCRIPTS) $(BINDIR)

to

cp $(BINARIES) $(BINDIR)
```

To make this restart safe, we put the command into `/etc/rc.local`:

```
# Enable CTS + RTS on P5 header for onboard serial
/usr/local/bin/gpio_setfunc 31 ALT3
/usr/local/bin/gpio_setfunc 30 ALT3
```

3-**Here is a sample of code that should allow to communicate with slaves.**

*[pymodbus rtu RS-485 communication](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/22712/pymodbus-rtu-rs-485-communication)*

Pay attention to the corrections below, the code block in the previous link.

```
temps  = client.read_input_registers(30001, 4, unit=0x0a) # Address, count, slave address
print temps.registers
coil  = client.read_coils(10001, 8, unit=0x0a) # Address, count, slave address
print coil.bits
```

In the sample code, replace the undesired USB port with the TTL one:

```
port="/dev/ttyUSB0"
to
port="/dev/ttyAMA0"
```

**All of this is untested, but that is a resume of all my findings up to now.**

Now my latest issue is that the slave has a big 12 V mark on the Modbus port. Will my Raspberry Pi get fried? I'll keep you posted.

## WARNING:

As Chris pointed out in the comments below, that amateur setup is untested and might fry your pi.

> You've got MAX485 connected to 5V and its D/R/DE/RE pins connected to Pi's GPIO >directly. This isn't safe as GPIO pins are designed to operate at 3.3V whereas >the R pin will send 5V signals (not sure if the other pins ever send 5V signals >from MAX485). This mistake seems so common and yet I haven't read someone >saying they actually burnt their pi doing that, so maybe it's usually fine, but >technically you should use a 5V to 3.3V level converter. Or replace MAX485 with >MAX3485 and power via 3.3Vcc pin.

Comment: Welcome and thanks for what appears to be a thoughtful answer.  I've removed your preamble about the nature of the Q&A, since, to clarify a significant detail indicated in comments on ppumkin's answer and the edit history, Ruthik asked a specific question and then **a week later** modified it to exclude the answer.   That is NOT a good way to go about things -- it is asking other people to waste their time trying to help after you've been too lazy to make your requirements known **in the first place**.  Something to consider WRT *"nothing is more annoying than people who ...."* ;)

Comment: Thank you for making my 1st post politically correct :-)

Comment: Based on the lack of update, I'm guessing this didn't work?  I'd love to do something like this on Raspberry Pi Zero W.

Comment: I ended up using an Arduino + RS232 to TTL Converter. (serial instead of Modbus) and was planning having the Arduino and RPI talk through I2C.
The main issue I had, was with the duplex comm. 
The timing of flicking the P5 pin to switch from tx to rx was a real pain with a half-plex MAX485. 
If you want to try MODBUS with a RPI, I highly recommend buying either 2 simplex chips or full-duplex like the MAX488 and MAX489 so you don't have to switch between tx / rx on the same line.
If your interest is more into having code to talk to a TS-MPPT-60, I would gladly share some of my Arduino code.

Comment: My interest is half-duplex (two-wire) with ability to toggle between transmit and receive in rs485 at 9600 baud to talk to a Tesla Wall Charger.  It needs to be 3.3Vcc powered and work with pi Zero W.  I'm planning on using MAX3485 or similar and controlling DE/RE pins via software using https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=33982 or https://sourceforge.net/p/arduino-icsc/wiki/Raspberry Pi/ code.  I know people have problems using software DE/RE at higher speed but it should be fine for 9600 baud.  For higher speed, MAX13487E is recommended but needs 5V.

Comment: Also, you've got MAX485 connected to 5V and its D/R/DE/RE pins connected to Pi's GPIO directly.  This isn't safe as GPIO pins are designed to operate at 3.3V whereas the R pin will send 5V signals (not sure if the other pins ever send 5V signals from MAX485).  This mistake seems so common and yet I haven't read someone saying they actually burnt their pi doing that, so maybe it's usually fine, but technically you should use a 5V to 3.3V level converter.  Or replace MAX485 with MAX3485 and power via 3.3Vcc pin.

Comment: Chris You are most probably completely right about the errors in my setup. I am an amateur. I couldn't find anything on the web to help me accomplish this so I made that lengthy post showing what I had up to that point hoping to find you. A bit sad you found this 2 years later, not when i was making that setup. I will add your comments to the post. Thank you.

Answer (score 7):

I do not think you will be able to directly connect the RS-485 to the RPi with software bitbanging.

It think the easiest way would be to use a USB <-> RS-485 device. Then you can use the USB as a serial port and let the rest happen as it should.

[image]

[I did find something like that at Farnell](http://uk.farnell.com/jsp/displayProduct.jsp?sku=1740357&CMP=KNC-GUK-FUK-GEN-LISTINGS&gross_price=true&CMP=KNC-GUK-FUK-GEN-LISTINGS&mckv=YKMwxwd8%7Cpcrid%7C14164337469%7Cplid%7C&gclid=CICUyKaAuL4CFbDJtAod1EsAGw) and it says it supports Linux 2.4+ - But the driver might need to get tweaked to work on ARM version of Linux. Then just use Python or whatever using built in Serial Port tools and code!

[image]

Thanks to  [Phil Vallone](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/users/13281/phil-vallone) for providing a solution to use the FTDI chip on the Pi

- [The answer to another question](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/14896/894)
- [A document dug out by Phil on how to install the FTDI chip on Pi](http://www.ftdichip.com/Support/Documents/AppNotes/AN_221_Adding%20an%20ADC_to%20a%20Raspberry_Pi.pdf)

Comment: +1 Here is a answer which provides a link to the FTDI drivers http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/14894/how-to-install-pitft-and-use-to-the-gpio-for-other-usage-like-serial-console/14896#14896

Comment: Thanks for the link. Really awesome that there is a solution. I will just add references to my answer also. THanks again.

Comment: Happy to Help - Here is the text version. http://www.ftdichip.com/Drivers/D2XX/Linux/ReadMe-linux.txt

Comment: adding detail to ppumkin's answer : RS485 uses voltage levels that are different than the Pi has available. And also uses what is called "differential" output

Comment: can't i use UART pins Rx and Tx ? whats the necessity in going for USB to UART convertion when i have UART pins on raspberry pi. i  will use ADM 485 . will this work?

Comment: @ppumkin pls see the edited question.

Comment: Well. What can I do? I answered you original question and you changed it substantially :( What's wrong with the USB device though?